# Joomla 2.5 Web Services

Tags: web-services, joomla2.5

I am currently working with Joomla 2.5 and I need to integrate our site with some other applications. We basically need web services but I don't seem to find any resources on the matter. I can find information on 1.5/1.6 but not 2.5.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had to go with something custom so I integrated Slim REST framework with Joomla. In the script below I initialize the Joomla application in my service script:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );

// Point JPATH_BASE to root directory    
define( 'JPATH_BASE', substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '/administrator')));    
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

// Include the Slim REST framework
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries/slim/Slim.php' );
// Include the Joomla framework
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );    

$application = & JFactory::getApplication('site');
$application->initialise();

$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/resource/car/:id', 'getCar');  
$app->put('/resource/car/:id', 'updateCar');
$app->run();
```

I can now use the Joomla APIs in my code for security, data access etc.

Comment: Did you have to change .htaccess to make it match the get/put/post routing?

Comment: I just had to allow the PUT method which was forbidden on the server; nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Ah I see. So the above is not implemented as a Joomla Component, but as a separate file located in the ROOT dir.  I though you had implemented it as a Joomla Component and was curious how you'd mapped the Slim routes to the component.

Comment: Yeah it is a separated file. This is not the actual implementation in my answer since I used the admin application instead. I used the security and data access APIs in my services which in a way is an integration rather than anything else.

Comment: What I meant was that I would have liked to implement it as a Joomla component (for packaging and configuration). That means the service would be invoked through a URL like this:  http://host/index.php?option=com_myrestservice   So my problem was, how to get Slim to map the configured routes onto the component.  I guess some tweaking of .htaccess would work.

Answer (score -1):

Since Joomla 1.6 onwards there is no need to activate webservices.

Therefore no corresponding option is available in the configuration page.